# How to make dynamic charts in Javascript with a JSON File

Tags: javascript, html, json

So, I am new to Javascript, but I have a code to make a stable bar chart, but I need to make it dynamic.
MY JSON File format is:
"valid_columns_counts": {
"Sr no.": 0,
"Domain": 37,
"Company Name": 0,
"Address": 36,
"Industry": 38,
"Phone Number": 30,
"Zipcode": 33,
"email": 14}

I ran this code:

```
window.onload = function () {

var dataPoints = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{

},
axisY: {
    title: "Percentage",
    titleFontColor: "#4F81BC",
},


toolTip: {
    shared: true
},
legend: {
    cursor:"pointer",
    itemclick: toggleDataSeries
},
data: 
{
    type: "column",
    name: "Consistency",
    legendText: "Consistency",
    axisYType: "secondary",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: dataPoints
}

});

function addData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPoints.push({
      x: data[i].valid_columns_counts
  y: data[i].valid_columns_counts
});
 }
}
 
chart.render();
$.getJSON("localhost/sample_output.json", addData);

}
```

But this code shows blank page when runned.Please if someone can help me.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No there is no console errors